# Javascript: object cannot be updated

Tags: javascript

I have an object named "order", and I am trying to change some values within in. Below is the code that I use, but it is showing me some weird behaviour.

All console.log output are included as comments after the corresponding line. As far as I can tell, the code is working because when I try to console.log the new value, it is correctly printed on the console.

The problem happens at my last line of code. When I am printing the entire object on console, and navigate to the two values that I just changed, they are both showing the old value "0.60", instead of the new value "1.00".

What is causing this bug?

```
console.log("this.calculate_discount(product)", this.calculate_discount(product)); // 0.40
console.log("order.SubTotalDiscount", this.order.SubTotalDiscount); // 0.60
this.order.SubTotalDiscount = parseFloat(this.calculate_discount(product)) +
                              parseFloat(this.order.SubTotalDiscount);
this.order.SubTotalDiscount = parseFloat(this.order.SubTotalDiscount).toFixed(2);
console.log("order.SubTotalDiscount", this.order.SubTotalDiscount); // 1.00
console.log("order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount",
                this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount); // 0.60
this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount = 
                parseFloat(this.calculate_discount(product)) +
                parseFloat(this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount);
this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount =
                parseFloat(this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount).toFixed(2);
console.log("order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount",
                this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount); // 1.00
console.log("order", this.order);
```

Thank you!

Update 2022-02-25

After some debugging, I have found that the problem is related to async(). This block of code is within an async(), and I have used await() after this block of code. I thought javascript runs from top to bottom, so I never thought this would be the cause of the problem.

```
async RedeemByPoints(product, index){
  this.selected_product(product);
  if(document.getElementById("btn_redeem_text_" + index).innerHTML == "Revert"){
    // DO SOMETHING...
    console.log("this.calculate_discount(product)", this.calculate_discount(product)); // 0.40
    console.log("order.SubTotalDiscount", this.order.SubTotalDiscount); // 0.60
    this.order.SubTotalDiscount = parseFloat(this.calculate_discount(product)) +
                                  parseFloat(this.order.SubTotalDiscount);
    this.order.SubTotalDiscount = parseFloat(this.order.SubTotalDiscount).toFixed(2);
    console.log("order.SubTotalDiscount", this.order.SubTotalDiscount); // 1.00
    console.log("order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount",
                this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount); // 0.60
    this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount = 
                parseFloat(this.calculate_discount(product)) +
                parseFloat(this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount);
    this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount =
                parseFloat(this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount).toFixed(2);
    console.log("order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount",
                this.order.totals[TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b')].Amount); // 1.00
    console.log("order", this.order);
    // DO SOMETHING...
    var taxes = await this.calculate_product_taxes(this.selected_item);
    // DO SOMETHING...
  } else {
    // DO SOMETHING...
  }
}
```

Even if I comment out the await() line, the problem persist. It will only disappear if I change the function to a normal function instead of an async(). But why?

As suggested by @MetBr , I am including all the objects and variables used in this script.

```
product{
  Deleted: (...)
  Discounted: (...)
  IsTakeOut: (...)
  ItemDiscountAmount: (...)
  ItemDiscountName1: (...)
  ItemDiscountName2: (...)
  ItemDiscountType: (...)
  ItemDiscountValue: (...)
  ItemNote: (...)
  ItemSubTotal: (...)
  ItemTaxTotalAmount: (...)
  K: (...)
  MinQty: (...)
  ModifierAmount: (...)
  ModifierString: (...)
  Name1: (...)
  Name2: (...)
  NoDiscount: (...)
  OnHold: (...)
  OrderDiscountAmount: (...)
  OrderDiscountType: (...)
  OrderDiscountValue: (...)
  PriceGroup: (...)
  PriceOverrideFlag: (...)
  PriceOverrided: (...)
  ProductIDn: (...)
  Qty: (...)
  Receipted: (...)
  ReferenceItemID: (...)
  SalePrice: (...)
  SelectedModifiers: (...)
  Status: (...)
  TaxTypeIDn: (...)
  Taxes: (...)
  TransactionNo: (...)
  TransactionType: (...)
  Type: (...)
  UnitPrice: (...)
  UnixTimestamp: (...)
  id: (...)
  modifiers: (...)
  sortN: (...)
}

order{
  ComputerName: (...)
  CustomerCount: (...)
  CustomerIDn: (...)
  DollarDiscount: (...)
  ExtraPoint: (...)
  IDn: (...)
  MenuIDn: (...)
  OrderDiscount: (...)
  OrderNote: (...)
  Printed_1: (...)
  Printed_2: (...)
  Printed_3: (...)
  ReferenceTransactionNo: (...)
  ReloadBalance: (...)
  ReloadPoint: (...)
  Status: (...)
  StoreName: (...)
  SubTotalAmount: (...)
  SubTotalDiscount: (...)
  TableIDn: (...)
  ToGo: (...)
  TotalAmount: (...)
  TotalItemCount: (...)
  TransactionNo: (...)
  Type: (...)
  UnixTimestamp: (...)
  UserIDn: (...)
  cur_customer: (...)
  id: (...)
  items: (...)
  payments: (...)
  reloadFlag: (...)
  reloadProductIDn: (...)
  totals: (...)
}

TOTAL_CODE_MAP.get('discount_b') will return 1
```

Comment: its a good thing your code is so easy to read, otherwise i might not want to spend the time to read it and help you

Comment: @Frederick would you please add also all objects you have in the script for example product is not defined like this

Comment: @MetBr I have updated the question, not sure if this is what you were asking for. Thank you!